# How do I fix a TypeError in a hover script?

Tags: javascript

I'm have a tooltip hover working, but I also get an error that I can't seem to fix. I've tried to replace "$" with jquery like suggested and also included no conflict mode, but then my 'tooltip' gets an error as being undefined. I feel like I'm going in circles. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Src: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

My tooltip works, but I have an error: TypeError: $ is not a function

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

I'd like to get rid of the error.

Comment: If you're getting `$ is not a function` then your code definitely **does not** work. The error means that you're not appropriately importing jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your response Pointy - but I don't understand...I am seeing the tooltip, it is actively working. Maybe my jQuery is being imported another way? Sorry I am clueless about this - I'm using WordPress with a bunch of other jQuery functions in tact through other plugins and my theme.

Comment: The `$` function **is** jQuery. If you're getting that error, it means that that relationship is broken. Unfortunately there are any number of ways that can get messed up, especially in a complicated WordPress setup because different plugins can conflict with each other.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I have no other errors but this error with this tiny script. :-(, but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a bit of guidance by Pointy I figured it out:

I guess my existing js didn't have the tooltip script. I added the bootstrap-tooltip.js file to my themes folder and changed my script source it:

```
<script src="/wp-content/themes/my-theme/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

Viola! No error.

Comment: Thank you for giving me that clue about importing the jQuery. :-)